# Rails 5 - cannot load data from associated model (belongs_to/has_one)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, belongs-to, has-one

I am having following scheme:

```
class Rental < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :tenant
end
class Tenant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :rental
end
```

So in the `rentals` DB table, there is a column called `tenant_id`.

I would like to display data about the tenant through the `rental` model, so I tried this:

```
@rental = Rental.find(params[:id])
puts @rental.tenant.inspect
```

But got the following error:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column tenants.rental_id does not exist LINE 1: SELECT "tenants".* FROM "tenants" WHERE "tenants"."rental_i... ^ : SELECT "tenants".* FROM "tenants" WHERE "tenants"."rental_id" = $1 LIMIT $2
```

What am I missing here yet? Did I forgot to add something to one or the other model?

Answer (score 1):

The Rails convention is to have the **foreign key on the `belongs_to` side**.

In your model

- `rental` has one `tenant` and
- `tenant` belongs to `rental`

...so your `tenants` table should have a `rental_id` column, not the other way around.

---

If you do not want to change your database schema, you can also change the model relations:

```
class Rental < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tenant
end

class Tenant < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :rental
end
```